# MSYS2 Mingw64 - lto-wrapper.exe: Create Process: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, mingw, msys2, mingw-w64

So, I have Windows 8.1 x64 with installed MSYS2. Using pacman I installed mingw64 gcc. I didn't change anything else.

Then I have a forked project that uses scons. Project is correct, it builds fine when others are trying to compile it.

The thing is that in the build scripts scons specifies flag `-flto` (link time optimization).

And I'm getting this error on final stage (linking exe file):

```
lto-wrapper.exe: fatal error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
D:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: error: lto-wrapper failed
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I found where `lto-wrapper.exe` lies, I tried to add this directory to the PATH. And almost every other category somehow related to mingw. Same error.

I'm ready to give more info to solve this problem.

Comment: This is a bug report. It would be better (and a much quicker path to a solution) to report this to the MSYS2 project directly.

Comment: I'm asking here because usually I'm doing something wrong and not the devs) But ok

Comment: The MSYS2 project just builds/packages everything, it should not be classified as "the devs" in the sense that they would be MinGW-w64 devs or GCC devs. Some do contribute, but that is irrelevant here. Your problem is most likely with the software distribution (heck, LTO may just be unsupported by MSYS2 binaries).

Comment: If it's unsupported why MSYS2 installs it then. Anyway, thanks, I'll set up a bug report

Comment: Well, this is GCC telling you it's not installed. But if it's not installed and GCC doesn't complain "LTO not compiled in" or something similar, I'd say it's a packaging bug. Hence, contact the package creator (MSYS2). Only they can answer your questions.